# Android audio delay

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem when playing an mp3 in android, is something like a delay or a lag, ex:

if I have to reproduce the following: "Hello, how are you?", it only plays "how are you?" or says very low the "hello".

It happens in a ViewSonic V220 its a 22" tablet, in most of other devices, it works fine, but is in that one that seems to fail.

Its weird, becouse other apps(like youtube or media player) works fine.

This is my code, maybe i am doing something wrong:

```
public class SoundManager implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
private Parent mParent;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

String[] mp3_array;
int counter = 0;

public SoundManager(Parent parent) {
    mParent = parent;
}

public void playSound(String[] url) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalStateException, IOException {
    mp3_array = url;
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url[0]);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}

public void stopMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        mp3_array = null;
        counter = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    try {

        Integer c = counter;

        if (mp3_array != null && counter + 1 < mp3_array.length) {
            mp.reset(); 
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            counter += 1;
            mp.setDataSource(mp3_array[counter]);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } else {
            if (mParent != null)
                mParent.invokeJs("playSoundEnded()");
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
            mp3_array = null;
            counter = 0;
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if (mParent != null)
        mParent.invokeJs("playSoundStarted()");
    mp.start();

}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps some sort of ramp-up to avoid pops when starting playback after the audio hardware has been inactive..? If you put 50 or 100 ms of silence at the beginning of your audio file, does this still happen?

Comment: Yes, i did something like that. I added an "..." at the begining of the string(before converting it to mp3)
Thanks